# Parsing list of list haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Hello I have a function that given a list it returns a subset of permutations of it. Now I want to make another function that given a list of list it produces another list of lists using the first function. To be more clear:

```
delete x [] = []
delete x (y:xs) = if (x==y) then (delete x xs)
                        else (y:delete x xs)

insert x n [] = []
insert x n xs = take (length xs - n) xs ++ [x] ++ drop (length xs - n) xs

insert_and_delete  x n xs= [insert x n (delete x xs)]

my_permutation x 0 list = insert_and_delete x 0 list
my_permutation x n list = insert_and_delete x n list   ++  my_permutation x (n-1) list

    --n is lenght of list
```

> ```
> my_permuation 5 4 [5,1,1,1]
> [[5,1,1,1],[5,1,1,1],[1,5,1,1],[1,1,5,1],[1,1,1,5]]
> my_permutation 3 3 [3,1,1]
> [[3,1,1],[1,3,1],[1,1,3]]
> ```

Now I want to make a function that given a list of lists eg `[[5,1,1,1] , [3,1,1]]` it will return a list containing all the results from above :

```
[[5,1,1,1],[5,1,1,1],[1,5,1,1],[1,1,5,1],[1,1,1,5],[3,1,1],[1,3,1],[1,1,3]]
```

My try so far:

```
generate_permutations2 [xs:list] = my_permutation  xs (length(xs:list)) (xs:list) ++ generate_permutations2 [list]
```

but when I try to call it I get:

```
generate_permutations2[ [2,1,1], [3,1]]
Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function generate_permutations2
```

**edit if change the aguments and add base case:**

```
generate_permutations2 [[]] = [[]]
generate_permutations2 (xs:list) = my_permutation  xs (length(xs:list)) (xs:list) ++ generate_permutations2 [list]
```

> Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0]  Expected
>   type: [t0]    Actual type: [[t0]]  In the expression: list  In the
>   first argument of `generate_permutations2', namely`[list]'  In the
>   second argument of `(++)', namely`generate_permutations2 [list]'

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is complaining that generate_permutations2 doesn’t handle the case where its input is the empty list. Add a clause for `generate_permutations2 []` just like you did with `insert` and `delete`.

Editorial:

Your intentions would be a lot clearer if you added type annotations to your functions. GHC is a lot better at getting to the root of the problem when you tell it the top-level types. Plus, other Haskell programmers are frequently used to inferring what you’re doing from type signatures.

Comment: And he needs to change it from `[xs:list]` to `(xs:list)`.  The former only matches on a list that contains a single sublist that has at least one element, the latter matches on a list with at least one sublist.

Comment: I added this generate_permutations2 [] = [[]] but I get the same message from compiler

Comment: @bheklilr I changed what you said and now it won't even compile!

Comment: @JmRag Can you provide more information than "won't compile"?

Comment: As bheklilr pointed out, `[x:xs]` (which has type [[a]]) isn’t the same thing as `(x:xs)` (which has type [a]). Which did you mean?

Comment: @JmRag Try `generate_permutations2 list` instead of `generate_permutations2 [list]`.  When you match on `(xs:list)` instead, `xs :: [a]` and `list :: [[a]]`.  You then try to do `generate_permutations2 [list]`, which is passing something of type `[[[a]]]` to that function, so you get an error saying it can't construct a type where `[[a]] ~ [[[a]]]`, which simplifies to `a ~ [a]`.